# I want to implement a simple multicast chat program. send thread and a receive thread are created and executed, but reception is not activated

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, multicast

I want to create two projects with this code so that they can chat with each other, but no matter how much I send, the data does not reach the other client.

I've been thinking and trying for hours on this problem, but it doesn't work. Various multicast chat programs on the web are written in languages other than C++, some use threads and some do not. To the best of my knowledge right now, I can't understand the codes on the web.

For fear of lengthy code, the basic header file and error output function have been omitted.

```
// header file and function declaration
#define MAXBUF 80
SOCKADDR_IN maddr;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int port;
    cout << "input port number" << endl;
    cin >> port;
    cout << "use port : " << port << endl;

    WSADATA wsa;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa))
    {
        err_display("WSAStartup");
        return -1;
    }

    //create send socket
    SOCKET r_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (r_sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        err_display(" recv socket");
        return -1;
    }

    //create recv socket
    SOCKET s_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (s_sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        err_display(" send socket");
        return -1;
    }


    // bind

    maddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    maddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    maddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if (bind(r_sock, (SOCKADDR*)&maddr, sizeof(maddr))) {
        err_display("bind");
        return -1;
    }

    // Join the Multicast address
    const char* mip = "236.0.0.1";
    IP_MREQ mreq;
    mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); // s_addr = 주소

    // Setting Multicast address
    if (!(inet_pton(AF_INET, mip, &mreq.imr_multiaddr))) {
        err_display("inet_pton");
        return -1;
    }
    // JOIN
    if (setsockopt(r_sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char*)&mreq, sizeof(mreq))) {
        err_display("setsockopt");
        return -1;
    } 



    while (true) {

        HANDLE h1 = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &sendf, (LPVOID)s_sock, 0, NULL);
        HANDLE h2 = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &recvf, (LPVOID)r_sock, 0, NULL);

    }

    closesocket(r_sock);
    closesocket(s_sock);
    WSACleanup();


    return 0;

}


unsigned __stdcall sendf(LPVOID arg) // send thread function
{

    SOCKET s_sock = (SOCKET)arg;
    char mesbuf[MAXBUF];

    int sendlen;
    while (1)
    {
        // send
        char mesbuf[MAXBUF];
        if (fgets(mesbuf, MAXBUF - 1, stdin) == NULL)
            break;
        cout << "send Thread" << endl;
        sendlen = strlen(mesbuf);
        sendto(s_sock, mesbuf, sendlen, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&maddr, sizeof(maddr));

    }
    return 0;
}

unsigned __stdcall recvf(LPVOID arg)  // recv thread function
{
    SOCKADDR_IN paddr; // peer address
    int namelen = sizeof(paddr);

    SOCKET r_sock = (SOCKET)arg;
    char mesbuf[MAXBUF];

    int recvlen;
    while (1)
    {
        char mesbuf[MAXBUF];
        //recive 
        recvlen = recvfrom(r_sock, mesbuf, MAXBUF - 1, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&paddr, &namelen);
        cout << "recv Thread" << endl;
        if (recvlen == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            err_display("recv error");
            closesocket(r_sock);
            break;
        }

        if (recvlen == 0)
        {
            cout << "normal close connection case" << endl;
            closesocket(r_sock);
            break;
        }

        mesbuf[recvlen] = '\0'; // string conversion
        cout << "from  : " << mesbuf << endl;


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How many send and receive threads do you want to create?

Comment: I only need a minimum thread to be a chat

Comment: Does your machine have more that one network interface?  If so, you'll need to be explicit about which one you use in both cases.

Comment: You have an infinite loop creating threads. Looks like a bit more than minimum.

Comment: I didn't care because I was going to verify a simple function and exit

Comment: First, do not use Reserved multicast addresses. Use something in the Organization-Local scope (`239.0.0.0/8`). Also, you cannot multicast between networks unless you use a multicast routing protocol, e.g. PIM, on every router in the path, which is why you cannot multicast on the public Internet.

Comment: understood. I wanted to run that code multiple times within my computer to enable chat between the programs that were run. However, the problem persisted even after changing the multicast address to 239.0.0.1.

Comment: You need to run multicast between different hosts. Inside your host, there is not layer-2 multicast. Remember that the layer-2 must also support multicast, which is why it does not work with some tunnels. Ethernet and Wi-Fi both support multicast.